# Searching through parallel arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program to search through parallel arrays on stores double values one string, I need to be able to search either by a certain value returning all values equal to or more than in the array and the same index in the string array.

I was able to write methods to sort the array like this

```
public static void Sortstrength(Double[] strength, String[] names, int sel) //method to sort beers alphabetically up and down
{
    String tmpStr; //temp string to help sort array
    Double tmpDbl; //temp double to help sort array

    if (sel == 1) //sort by names ascending if sel int = 1
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < strength.length - 1; t++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strength.length - 1; i++) {
                if (strength[i].compareTo(strength[i + 1]) > 0) {
                    tmpStr = names[i];
                    tmpDbl = strength[i];
                    names[i] = names[i + 1];
                    strength[i] = strength[i + 1];
                    names[i + 1] = tmpStr;
                    strength[i + 1] = tmpDbl;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s %s \n", names[i], strength[i]);
        }
    } else //sort by names descending
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < strength.length - 1; t++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strength.length - 1; i++) {
                if (strength[i].compareTo(strength[i + 1]) < 0) {
                    tmpStr = names[i];
                    tmpDbl = strength[i];
                    names[i] = names[i + 1];
                    strength[i] = strength[i + 1];
                    names[i + 1] = tmpStr;
                    strength[i + 1] = tmpDbl;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%-15s %s \n", names[i], strength[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to alter this if it is even possible to do so but any help would be appreciated as I am pretty stuck

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not create a thread for each array, and a cancel token for each so that when one finds the target, the rest stop?

Comment: Anything wrong with a `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Beer holding a double and a string value. Add the Beers to a list and use a Comperator to sort. Output the list.

```
public class Beer
{
    private final double strength;
    private final String name;

    public Bear(final String name, final double strength)
    {
       this.strength = strength;
       this.name = name;
    }

     public String getName() { return name; }
     public double getStrength() { return strength; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To search your data with `strength` array sorted in ascended order use `binarySearch`:

```
double threshold = 2.0d;
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(strength, threshold);
if (index < 0) { 
    index = -index - 1;
}
```

since your two arrays are "synced" this index will match your String array.

Note, you could implement "binding" of strength/names data and their sorting much cleaner and more effectively in at least two different ways :

- use Map to store your bindings assuming your `strength` keys are unique, and then sorting by keys.
- Use helper POJO class `MyData` holding both strength and name, as in *Hannes*'s answer and [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) array of `MyData` objects supplying custom `Comparator`, then do [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with same comparator to find index according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you actually want is a sorted map from Doubles to Strings. Use TreeMap:

```
private final TreeMap<Double, String> map = new TreeMap<>(); //for descending order use .reverseMap()
public SortedMap<Double, String> getKeysAbove(double key) {
    return map.subMap(key, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}
public static void exampleUsage() {
    Mapper mapper = new Mapper(); //or whatever class name
    mapper.map.put(1D, "Goodbye");
    mapper.map.put(2D, "Hello, ");
    mapper.map.put(3D, "World!");
    for (Entry<Double, String> e : mapper.getKeysAbove(1.5).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```